# sed parsing with regex

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a file:

```
"data_personnel": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Mathieu"
    }
],
"struct_hospital": [
    {
        "id": "9",
        "geo": "chamb",
        "nb": ""
    },
    {
        "id": "",
        "geo": "jsj",
        "nb": "SMITH"
    },
    {
        "id": "10",
        "geo": "",
        "nb": "12"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "geo": "marqui",
        "nb": "20"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "geo": "oliwo",
        "nb": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "geo": "par",
        "nb": "5"
    }
]
```

I do this command for get all value of geo in struct_hospital

```
sed -n "/\"struct_hospital\"/,/^\],$/s/^[[:blank:]]*\"geo\":[[:blank:]]\+\"\([^\"]*\)\",/\1/p my_file
```

What should I change on my sed command for get all value of nb ?
geo is: "geo":"value",  (with comma)
nb is: "nb":"value"      (without comma)

I don't understand ..

Comment: This looks like some `JSON` format. Better use a programming language with a decent parser module (`Python`, `PHP`, just to name a few) - it will be **a lot** easier.

Comment: There's also `jq` as command-line tool that specialize in handling JSON

Comment: I have to get value with sed. Just for get value ..

Comment: @Crazy, did you post the whole input? Could something be missed?

Answer (score 3):

The right way with **`jq`** tool:

> get all value of **nb**

```
echo "{ $(cat yourfile) }" | jq -r '.struct_hospital[].nb'
```

The output:

```
 
SMITH
12
20
1
5
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you correctly, this works for your input

```
sed -n "/\"struct_hospital\"/,/^\],$/s/^[[:blank:]]*\"nb\":[[:blank:]]\+\"\([^\"]*\)\"$/\1/p" my_file
```

The difference is that there's an end-of-line character (`$`) rather than a comma. (And I've added a missing double quote)

Comment: Oh. It worked for me. Your original needed an extra quote mark to make it work. Does it produce an error message, or the wrong output?

Comment: @Crazy make sure you didn't make a mistake in your question then, because it looks like [it should work](https://ideone.com/b8K69l).

Comment: Maybe there's whitespace between the quote and the end-of-line in my_file.

Answer (score 0):

With the exact text you provided, the following `sed` command would be enough to output all the "nb" values :

```
sed -n 's/.*"nb": "\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p'
```

[ideone test](https://ideone.com/lSYOfP) (note that ideone trims the leading empty line corresponding to the first empty "nb" value, but you should get it when executing the command).